# Module gives private methods to mixed in class. But why?

Tags: ruby, module

I am a bit confused. We have next example:

```
module A
  private
    def give_private
      p 'private'
    end
end

class B
  include A
  def give_public
     give_private()
  end
end

return is:
#=> private
```

Seems like I can use private methods of module, not from module.
Doesn't it just wrong?
Can somebody explain why, so?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Including a module into a class basically makes the module a superclass of the class. So, method lookup works just like with any other superclass.

Comment: That is wright, but in normal OOP we cannot use private methods of superclass, right?